# Coloring a Voronoi Graph

Tags: unity, c#, 2d, graph

**Intro:**

I want to convert a Voronoi Graph made with this awesome [library](https://github.com/jceipek/Unity-delaunay) by jceipek on GitHub into something I can work on.

So far so good, this user provides with a demo to start with and shows how to generate the VG.

**Question:**

**How do I convert the VG (made by edges and that dot in the middle) into something that I can work with?**

Such as, after you generate some noise and apply to it (height), you colour the polygons based on it.

**Thoughts:**

Something comes to my mind about instantiating meshes and tiles based on the edges and the position of the dot as a start, but it won't work if I can't "detect" the polygon.

**Expected result:**

Image from this blog about Voronoi Mapping [link](https://azgaar.wordpress.com/2017/03/30/voronoi-graph/)

[image]

**What I have:**

[image]

It is drawn with Gizmos (for visual debugging in Unity)

I want to know how to color my polygons as in the expected image above. So I thought about doing a mesh or individual tile (and color it based on height afterwards but that is sauce for another question if needed)

**Edit of my progress:**

To further explain this question I provide the next image.

[image: It shows a cube inside one of the many edges inside the VG]

The image shows that I could use that position data somehow and turn that random polygon shape into a "tile" that will have a colour (mesh?) and possible data in it (script).

I hope this helps otherwise let me know in the comments.

Comment: To be clear, you're asking about "rendering" a Voronoi graph, correct? Not about [graph colouring (the algorithmic problem of choosing "colour" labels so that no two adjacent nodes use the same label)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring)? If so, I recommend editing your title to avoid confusion, and including an example image or mock-up of what your input and desired output look like.

Comment: Edit done with my expected results about it.

Comment: Can you be more clear about "into something i can work on" - what do you exactly need and expect? A model, a bitmap, a vector image, a something else?

Comment: Hm... it's not clear to me how this image relates to "after you generate some noise and apply to it (height) you colour the polygon based on it." Can you explain step-by-step? And define what "it" is in each case (the graph? The noise value? The resulting height?)

Comment: Might the last comment in this thread (by Yandalf) be what you are looking for? https://forum.unity.com/threads/delaunay-voronoi-diagram-library-for-unity.248962/

Comment: More or less it is, but i would like a simple example if its not too much of an asking.

Answer (score 3):

While you could detect the polygon, it would be simpler to directly use the data that was used to generate them.

If you check `Voronoi.cs` there is a method called `Regions ()` which returns a `List<List<Vector2>>`. Each sub list is list of points for a given region. From there you can turn the points into a mesh.

Comment: If I understand correctly, I think they're looking for help with that last step: turning the region data provided by the Voronoi library into a mesh.

Comment: In addition to where it is suggested to use `Regions()`, OP will also want to construct a sub-mesh for each tile, set its vertex colours according to the colour you want, and then use a vertex colouring shader / material on it. Alternatively pick a material on which the colour can be set as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

So you can do this by placing a cone mesh (tip facing the camera) at each point.

Assuming each cone has a unique color (and sufficient radius), the depth buffer should automatically "segment" your colors (assuming an ortho camera).